# FileNotFoundException in Eclipse after Java updated

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload

I have a program in which the client uploads a file and the file is stored in a database.  Prior to Java updating on my computer, my project was working fine.  Now I am getting a `FileNotFoundException`.  Eclipse is telling me:

> The JAR file C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar has no source
>   attachment.

Anybody come across this problem?

My servlet code for uploading the file is standard:

```
if (!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request))
    {return;}

try 
{ 
  List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
  courseID = items.get(0).getString();
  homeworkID = items.get(1).getString();
  File storeFile = new File(items.get(2).getName());
  String fileName = storeFile.getName();
  String mimeType = new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(storeFile); //for putting file into database
  putFileIntoDB(uName, courseID, homeworkID, fileName, mimeType, storeFile);
}//try
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
   request.setAttribute("msg", "There was an error: " + ex.getMessage());
   request.getRequestDispatcher("/upload.jsp").forward(request, response);
  }
```

There error is found in the putFileIntoDB method when the FileInputStream is created in the line fis=new FileInputStream(f):

```
void putFileIntoDB(String username, String courseID, String homeworkID, String fileName, String mime, File f) throws SQLException, IOException
{   
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    java.sql.PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    java.sql.Connection conn = null;
    try {
            conn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
            conn.setAutoCommit(true);

            fis = new FileInputStream(f);

            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into files(username, courseID, assignmentID, fileName, mimeType, contents) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            pstmt.setString(1, username);
            pstmt.setString(2, courseID);
            pstmt.setString(3, homeworkID);
            pstmt.setString(4, fileName);
            pstmt.setString(5, mime);
            pstmt.setAsciiStream(6, fis, (int) f.length());

            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            conn.commit();
        }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally
    {
      pstmt.close();
      fis.close();
      conn.close();
    }
}
```

Anybody else come across this problem?

Comment: have you checked if that jar is available on that location?

Comment: Yes, when I navigate to that location, the rt.jar file is there. That's why I don't understand why it's telling me it has no source attachment.

Answer (score 1):

Try below steps;

Step 1 - Configure Eclilpse to use the JDK and not the JRE.

```
Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs
Click "Add", "Standard VM", "Next"
For "JRE Home" click "Directory"
Locate your JDK directory...
Ex: C:\java\jdk1.6.0_24
Click "Finish"
Next check the JDK vs the JRE that is listed.
Click "Ok"
```

Step 2 - Configure your Project to use the JDK because it was created with the JRE as the "Installed JRE".  New project should be OK.

```
Right click the project's name.
Choose "Properties", "Java Build Path"
Click the tab "Libraries".
Click "Add Libraries", select "JRE System Library", Next
Select the bottom item: Workspace default JRE (jdk1.x.x. etc....)
(Notice that it is now a JDK and not the JRE!)
Click "Finish"
Now remove the JRE libarary so you only have the JDK library.
ex: JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.6]
Click "OK"
```

Comment: Well I tried this and unfortunately I'm still having the same problem.  I don't know what happened to my eclipse setup.  I'm considering unistalling it and reinstalling it.  Do you know if there is a way to revert back to a previous time when it was working?

Comment: no you can't revert. Check the similar isse here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367286/m2eclipse-is-unable-to-locate-c-program-files-java-jre6-lib-tools-jar